# Converting plain text tweets to include hyperlinks

Tags: regex, perl

I have exported my data from Twitter in order to include my tweets on my personal blog. I have each tweet from the past 10 years in plain text. An example is this:

`When a new startup enters your industry and innovates around you, winning your customers and taking your revenues, if you fail to transform your own business in response, are you negligent? Do shareholders have a claim against you? https://myurl.com/blah #Governance #liability #corporatenegligence`

I'd like to process the each tweet and add HTML anchor tags to any URLs and tags found in the text. So basically anything with http/https turns into a link and anything with a hash before it turns into a link.

I'm struggling to come up with a regex to do this. The anchor tag for URLs just uses the URL itself as the href. The href on tags is https://twitter.com/hashtag/TAG where TAG is the tag text after the # and before a non alphanumeric character.

Each tweet is stored in an array of scalars called `@tweets`. So looping through them is straight forward.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: just split each scalar by whitespace, check with regex for http+ https+ #+ strings and substitute these strings?

Comment: @Chris: Splitting on white space seems like an unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like some pretty basic regexes will be useful.

A link is "http://" or "https://" followed by a series of non-whitespace characters - `https?://S+`.

A hashtag is a hash followed by a series of alpha-numeric characters - `#\w+`.

So, the code could look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

$_ = join '', <DATA>;

# Before
say;

# Convert links
s|(https?://\S+)|<a href="$1">$1</a>|g;

# Convert hashtags
s|#(\w+)|<a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/$1">#$1</a>|g;

# After
say;

__DATA__
When a new startup enters your industry and innovates around you, winning
your customers and taking your revenues, if you fail to transform your own
business in response, are you negligent? Do shareholders have a claim against
you? https://myurl.com/blah #Governance #liability #corporatenegligence
```

Comment: That worked an absolute treat - thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [URL::Search](https://metacpan.org/pod/URL::Search). It will handle many edge cases like URLs followed or surrounded by punctuation:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URL::Search '$URL_SEARCH_RE';

$text =~ s{($URL_SEARCH_RE)}{<a href="$1">$1</a>}g;
```

But there is another problem. URLs and the surrounding text must be HTML-escaped if you want to use the result as HTML, but you don't want to HTML-escape your valid HTML of course. To solve this you could split the string into URLs and non-URL sections, escape both and wrap the URLs, and then join them back together. Fortunately URL::Search has a partition_urls function designed just for this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use URL::Search 'partition_urls';
use HTML::Entities;

my $text = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $output = '';
foreach my $section (partition_urls $text) {
  my $escaped = encode_entities $section->[1];
  if ($section->[0] eq 'URL') {
    $output .= qq{<a href="$escaped">$escaped</a>};
  } else {
    $escaped =~ s{(?<!\S)#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)}{<a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/$1">#$1</a>}g;
    $output .= $escaped;
  }
}

print $output;

__DATA__
When a new startup enters your industry and innovates around you, winning
your customers and taking your revenues, if you fail to transform your own
business in response, are you negligent? Do shareholders have a claim against
you? https://myurl.com/blah #Governance #liability #corporatenegligence
```

There is an additional complication in that hashtags must be URI-escaped to be used in a URL, *before* HTML escaping, but limiting what is allowed in hashtags to ASCII letters and digits `[a-zA-Z0-9]` avoids this problem... The alternative is that you have to split the non-URL sections again into hashtags and non-hashtag text to do separate processing.